# using c# for mobile game development

Tags: c#, mobile

I'm thinking of developing mobile game app using c#. I'm pretty sure about server side but not clear about client side.

- Can i use unity & c# to deploy mobile app to android or apple?
- If not, do i have any other alternatives or combination to do that?
- Xamarin doesn't seem to be a good choice for game development.
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can i use unity & c# to deploy mobile app to android or apple?

[Manual - UnityCloudBuildSupportedPlatforms](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCloudBuildSupportedPlatforms.html)

> iOS
>
> Android
>
> Windows desktop
>
> Mac OS desktop
>
> Linux desktop
>
> WebGL
>
> Unity Web Player (Unity 5.3 and below, legacy versions of Unity only)

#### If not, do i have any other alternatives or combination to do that?

Though the answer is yet, there are multiple other options, namely:

1. [Godot engine](https://godotengine.org/features) - It is also opensource and provides full C++ support
2. [Unreal engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/index.html) - Also supports major consoles
3. Many more if you research this a bit, but I think you are covered with the above.

#### Xamarin doesn't seem to be a good choice for game development.

You can use it, but you are essentially using [monogame](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/build-your-first-game-with-monogame-getting-started/)

Comment: thanks for the response. Looks like .net is not best language for the mobile game..
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/game-development-with-net/
Anyway your answer was useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Unity and, as far as I know, is one of the main framework for game development with C#